# Please explain the flow of this error => ejabberd_odbc:log:669 p1_mysql_conn: Connection closed, exiting

Tags: logging, connection, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd-15.11 .  Every morning after starting my PC , I check my ejabberd logs and error logs using putty. That time I usually get this error:

```
 [error] <0.5058.0>@ejabberd_odbc:log:663 p1_mysql_conn: Connection closed, exiting.
```

I know that it occurs because there has been no requests to the server all night and hence after some default set time, server goes to sleep. But here I want to know that why this error occurs? who triggers this error? I want to understand clearly the control flow from the start when this condition occurs and then the subsequent actions that are taken through the functions. I actually want to know the flow of control through the functions.

I found that in ejabberd_odbc.erl file , the error is displayed on line no: 663 in a function called `log(Level, Format, Args)` but I am in search of the function from which this log function gets called so that I can climb up the ladder and finally can find how the control flows.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because MySQL closed the connection, generally due to inactivity.
ejabberd will reconnect anyway, so it is not a problem.
However, if you want ejabberd to create traffic to keep the connection alive, you can use option `sql_keepalive_interval` as described in ejabberd documentation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#relational-databases

Comment: Thank you very very much  Sir @Mickael Remond. I am very happy to get the answer directly from the Founder of Process-one. Thank you once again. Sir I have many questions to ask regarding ejabberd. Could you please tell me where can I communicate with you about my questions..?